# Lucene index segment file not found

Tags: lucene, umbraco

I've got application using Lucene examinesearcher on a Umbraco site, when the app attempts to do a search I get a segment file not found error.

Could not find file '\n5200-2\iis7_www\a\r\mysite\www\App_Data\TEMP\ExamineIndexes\nForumEntryIndexSet\Index\segments_a'.

After googling I found that it could be because multiple processes are trying to access or write to the index at the same time.

I've tried rebuilding the index and the error still occurs.

How can I find out what is trying to access the index? The site is on shared hosting.

UPDATE: Is the hosting being on Medium trust an issue?

Comment: No, Umbraco should run fine in medium trust.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you don't have 'write' permissions on the app_data folder.

It's not entirely clear from your question but if you are using Examine, there shouldn't be a need to "roll your own" indexing process as Umbraco does this for you. If you have then this would certainly cause an issue too.

Comment: The app_data folder has write permissions, it looks like it is writing and updating the segment files looking at the modified dates.

Yeah it's using Examine for searching.

I've got an exact copy of the site on my dev machine and I can't recreate the issue, is there some server settings causing an issue?

Comment: I know this sounds "brute force" but try deleting the External index (not Media index) and then restart the application by touching the web.config. This should recreate the index from scratch. It may be that it's just fallen over itself.